# How to use spherical law of cosines to find distance of two cities on earth?

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

I know the spherical law of cosines, namely $\cos (c)=\cos (a) \cos (b)+\sin (a) \sin (b) \cos (C)$, where the lengths of each side arch of the spherical triangles are $a,b,c$ and the angle of the corner opposite to side $c$ is $C$.

Now consider Beijing ($39.9042°$N, $116.4074°$E), and Philadelphia ($39.9526°$N, $75.1652$°W) and that the circumference of the earth is $24,901$ miles.

I need to find the distance between the two cities, but I don't know how to proceed since I don't know any side lengths of a triangles (I also don't know which triangles I would use, I am assuming we then connect each city to the point ($0°$,$0°$). But if we did, I still don't know how to find those distances.

Any help would be appreciated to proceed with this problems. I have never worked with longitudes/latitudes.

Comment: By the way, those coordinates have ridiculously many significant digits. As given, they're purporting to pinpoint each of Philadelphia and Beijing to a precision of around _10 meters_ -- and if that kind of precision is really important to you, you can't afford to assume that the Earth is an exact sphere anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a triangle with corners at your two cities (A and B) and the north pole (C). Then everything you need on the *right* side of your law can be read off from the lat/long of the cities. More specifically, $a$ and $b$ are $90^\circ$ minus each latitude, and $C$ is the difference in longitude.